# Doxygen не создает ссылку на специализацию класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, doxygen

Помогите плез.
Имеется следующий код

```
template<class T, class T_Step>
constexpr bool
is_forbidden_types_combination = !std::is_floating_point_v<T> && std::is_floating_point_v<T_Step>;


template<class T, class T_Step = T, class T_Access = void>
class RangeIdManager;

template<class T, class T_Step>
class RangeIdManager<T, T_Step, std::enable_if_t<!is_forbidden_types_combination<T, T_Step>>>
{
    ...
}
```

Далее я использую Doxygen для документации.
Описания всех методов, переменных и прочего находятся в том же хедере что и сам код.
Но описания не разбросаны по всему хедеру, а собраны в одном месте

```
/**
 * @var is_forbidden_types_combination
 *
 * @brief ...
 *
 * ...
 */

/**
 * @class RangeIdManager
 *
 * @brief ...
 *
 * ...
 */


template<class T, class T_Step>
constexpr bool
is_forbidden_types_combination = !std::is_floating_point_v<T> && std::is_floating_point_v<T_Step>;


template<class T, class T_Step = T, class T_Access = void>
class RangeIdManager;

template<class T, class T_Step>
class RangeIdManager<T, T_Step, std::enable_if_t<!is_forbidden_types_combination<T, T_Step>>>
{
    ...
}
```

Первое описание будет применено к переменной. Второе к RangeIdManager который стоит первым

```
template<class T, class T_Step = T, class T_Access = void>
class RangeIdManager;
```

Но как задокументировать специализацию? Если я пишу так

```
/**
 * @class RangeIdManager<T, T_Step, std::enable_if_t<!is_forbidden_types_combination<T, T_Step>>>
 *
 * @brief ...
 *
 * ...
 */
```

это не работает. Я много разных вариантов попробовал, ничего не выходит.
На всякий случай документация в гите https://github.com/lelezard7/ONF/tree/main/doc там надо зайти *html/index.html* если что.

Такая же проблема появляется если я хочу создать ссылку на данную специализацию.
Обычно достаточно упомянуть в тексте описания сигнатуру метода, функции, класса, переменной и т.д. и Doxygen создаст ссылку в это место. Если он ее не создает автоматически, можно указать `@ref <name>` и готово. Но все это не работает со специализацией. Что делать?

Если будут дополнительные замечания по коду, можете тоже высказать, буду благодарен.

**Дополнено:**

Версия Doxygen - 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b).

Вывод `Doxygen -x Doxyfile`

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.1 (ef9b20ac7f8a8621fcfc299f8bd0b80422390f4b)
PROJECT_NAME           = ONF
PROJECT_BRIEF          = "╨Э╨╡╨▒╨╛╨╗╤М╤И╨░╤П, ╤А╨░╨╖╨╜╨╛╤А╨╛╨┤╨╜╨░╤П ╨▒╨╕╨▒╨╗╨╕╨╛╤В╨╡╨║╨░"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = .
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = Russian
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
INPUT                  = ../include \
                         .
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, спросите на английском сайте stackoverflow, чтобы я мог прокомментировать / ответить. Я не говорю по-русски (это сообщение было переведено автоматически).

Comment: Версия Doxygen? Настройки Doxygen отличаются от настроек по умолчанию (т.е. вывод команды doxygen -x)

Comment: @albert я обновил описание вопроса. Снизу дописал.

Comment: Это конечно не ответ, но не проще писать комменты прямо перед тем, что они описывают? Это и при чтении кода удобнее.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , можно конечно. Я уже подумываю об этом. Просто таким образом сам код получается засорен разными описаниями. Сложнее в нем ориентироваться. Описания там большие получаются.

Comment: Нормальные IDE умеют сворачивать и фигурные скобки, и комменты (как минимум блочные). Сразу становится удобнее.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , справедливо. Ну если никто не даст ответ в течении дня, сделаю так как вы говорите. Если верить тому что я смог накопать, Doxygen не умеет нормально работать с частичной специализацией. Правда это инфа 10-й давности.